# Bash autocomplete an option without running the application

Tags: c++, linux, readline, libreadline

I have found this code as a bash autocomplete. But, it looks strange to me. What if I do not like to run the code at all. If I would like to type `./a.out` then space (without entering) and then by pressing tab, I would like to see only two options `apple` and `cherry` and if I type `a` and press tab, then it autocomplete the option `apple` and similarly for `c`. Let's say only one of the two options are acceptable:

```
./a.out apple
./a.out cherry
```

where `apple` and `cherry` are options and not the name of the files in the directory. In the first case, I would like the program types that `your option is apple` and in the second case `your option is cherry`. In any other case, the program should print an error that the option is not valid.

All examples that I find on the internet such as what follows look like that you should run the program first, then it reacts. The while loop inside the `main` function collides with the normal functionality of the program. Have I misunderstood the `readline` library? Is the above-described application possible to implement by editing the following code?

```
// sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
// g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lreadline

#include <iostream>

#include "readline/readline.h"
#include "readline/history.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char *line;
    while ((line = readline("? ")) != nullptr) {
        cout << "[" << line << "]" << endl;
        if (*line) add_history(line);
        free(line);
    }
// if(argc!=2)
// {
//  cout<<"<exe> one_parameter"<<endl;
//  return 1;
// }
// string option=argv[1];
// if(option=="apple" || option=="cherry")
//  cout<<"Your option is "<<option<<endl;
// else
// {
//  cout<<"Error: invalid option "<<option<<endl;
//  return 1;
// }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want bash to autocomplete, you need to configure bash autocompletion. If you want your program to have a command line interface with autocomplete, readline is a good library for that.

Comment: Typically bash completion is not implemented as part of the executable whose options are completed, but in a separate bash-completion script. You might want to have a look at https://iridakos.com/tutorials/2018/03/01/bash-programmable-completion-tutorial.html which explains how to create completion for a very simple bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your executable. You need to put this in a file and source (`source autocomplete_file` or `. autocomplete_file`) it in the bash.

```
_a_complete_()
{
    local word=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    local files='apple cherry'

    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${files}" -- ${word} ) )
}

complete -F _a_complete_ ./a.out
```

[Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) a nice documentation can be found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This script did not work for me.

Comment: Please try again. I made an auto-complete script for `a `and not for `a.out`. I corrected the error above.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

// partial answer - why you may want to invoke the app while doing the autocompletion

One way of implementing the autocomplete for an application is to have the application binary configure it (by having a flag that prints the instructions for autocomplete configuration or by just parsing the `--help` output of the application).

Schemataically:

```
complete -F $(./a.out --generate-autocomplete-config) ./a.out
```

This is why you might see the binary actually invoked as a part of autocomplete implementation.

Comment: Very clever. Thanks a lot.